# Hibernate: How to return the last id of an object?

Tags: hibernate, return

When I created a new Cocktail, I want exactly that Cocktail to be returned. I tried already several approaches, but hence I am new to hibernate and - programming - I am not even sure if my syntax is correct...

My latest code snippet -->

My CocktailDao:

```
// Return last created Cocktail

        Session session;

        public Cocktail getLastCocktail(){
            return (Cocktail) session.createSQLQuery("Select LAST_INSERT_ID()").uniqueResult();

        }
```

My CocktailController:

```
  // Create Cocktail
        @RequestMapping(value="/EditCocktail.html", method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView edit(@RequestParam(required=false) Integer id) {
            log.debug("EditCocktail.html");
            ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
            if (id==null){
                mv.addObject(new Cocktail());
            } else {
                mv.addObject(cocktailDao.findById(id));
            }
            mv.setViewName("edit-cocktail");
            return mv;
            }

    //Get last created cocktail in order to continue with editing the cocktail 
        @RequestMapping(value="/CreateCocktail.html", method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView lastCocktail(@RequestParam(required=false) Integer id) {
            ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
            mv.addObject("title", "Cocktails");
            mv.addObject("message", "Stellen Sie den Cocktail fertig");
            mv.addObject("cocktail", cocktailDao.getLastCocktail());
            System.out.println("_____________________________________________________________" + id);
            mv.addObject("edit", false);
            mv.setViewName("list-cocktail");
            return mv;
        }
```

Right now I am getting following error message:

```
Jun 22, 2013 1:03:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [DrinkersParadise] in context with path [/DP] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at de.hdu.pms.ctrl.CocktailController.lastCocktail(CocktailController.java:103)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Where are you calling `create()` method of `CocktailDao.java` from?

Comment: good question... actually nowhere... Nevermind, creating a Cocktail works, but I am not able to get the last entered id. So basically my problem is in the method getLastCocktail();

Comment: I just asked because if you want to get the last inserted record's id just after `create()`, you don't need to write separate method.

Comment: ok... and how would you do that? E.g. with a session.save(c) and session.refresh(c)?

Comment: As per the `create()` method, when you save `c (instance of Cocktail)`, that `c` will have its Id. so you can return `c.getId()` from the `create()` itself.

Comment: Thanks, but this did not solve my problem.

Comment: What isolation level is Hibernate set to use? If you SELECT for the latest ID, are you sure that no phantom reads can occur? Edit: you don't even run the insert and get latest ID calls in the same transaction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Hibernate, you get the save method, it returns the Id, of the saved Object. Once you saved, just get the Id, find in the database, in order to retrieve your cocktail. Check the code below :

```
    public Integer addCocktail(String yourProperties){
      Session session = factory.openSession();
      Transaction tx = null;
      Integer cocktailID = null;
      try{
         tx = session.beginTransaction();
         Cocktail mycockTail =  new Cocktail(yourProperties);
         cocktailID = (Integer) session.save(mycockTail); 
         tx.commit();
      }catch (HibernateException e) {
         if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
         e.printStackTrace(); 
      }finally {
         session.close(); 
      }
      return cocktailID;
   }
```

Hope it's helped !!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I still have an issue with my method, but it should work somehow like this:

CocktailDao:

```
//  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
//  public List<Cocktail> findLast() {
//      Session session = getSession();
//      String hql = "select MAX(tbl_cocktail.id) from tbl_cocktail";
//      Query query  = session.createQuery(hql);
//      List<Cocktail> list = query.list();
//      return list;
//
//  }
```

CocktailController:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/CreateCocktail.html", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView findLast() {
ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();

    mv.addObject("title", "Cocktails");
    mv.addObject("message", "Stellen Sie den Cocktail fertig");
    mv.addObject("cocktail", cocktailDao.findLast());
    mv.addObject("edit", false);
    mv.setViewName("list-cocktail");
    return mv;
}
```